# Mongoose save on populated document

Tags: mongoose, save

I have a problem saving populated document in `MongoDB`. I am using `mongoose` and for the most part it works pretty well and intuitive. Not on `populate` however, and sadly the documentation is very poor to reflect on this issue.

I have 3 models: `User`, `Topic`,`Answer`. A `User` can have `Topic` and the `Topic` can have `Answers`. Each answer has `author` - `User`. These relations are defined the appropriate way:

```
type: { type: mongoose.Types.Schema.ObjectId, ref: '...' }
```

I figured out how to do nested population. In my case, to use the `author` of an `answer`, when given a `topicId`, the population looks like this:

```
.populate({
    path: 'answers',
    populate: {
        path: 'author'
    }
})
```

And it works. I have access to all the documents. However when I am deleting a 'Topic' i want to delete all the `Answers` as well. Also I need to remove the `Topic._id` from its `User`(author) document and I need to remove the `Answers._ids` from their authors respectively. The code looks like this:

```
let topicIdIndex = topic.author.topics.indexOf(topicId);
topic.author.topics.splice(topicIdIndex, 1);
topic.author.save();
```

I remove the `id` with `splice`, but when i call `topic.author.save()` it simply does not save the populated document `author` of model `User`. I don't understand why, because I know for a fact that `model` instances carry all the mongoose functionality within themselves - that's why when `debugging` you can see the actual `data` in the `_doc` field.

Is there no way to save in such a manner? Do I really have to make manual searches for each `id` I need removed?